# mysql_query for update dates in WordPress database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Can someone helps me with what should be the query(mysql_query) for update dates(date=now) of all post in specific category (ex. cat_id=164) in WordPress database?

Comment: please provide you question detail properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your database then the query may be:

```
UPDATE wp_posts a
SET post_date = NOW()
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM wp_term_relationships b WHERE b.object_id=a.ID AND b.term_taxonomy_id=164);
```

Where the `164` is the category id.
If you have other prefix than `wp_` in your wp tables, just change it with your.